# nginx: Too many redirect

Tags: nginx

I need to create a nginx configuration with redirect, this is my conf:

```
server {

listen          8080;
server_name     test.example.org;
index           index.php index.html;
return          301 $scheme://test.example.org/dashboard;
location        /dashboard {
    alias           /path/to/files;
    index           index.php index.html;
    }
}
```

I need redirect test.example.org to test.example.org/dashboard,when i go to test.example.org, my browser get an error "Too many redirects"

Comment: I'm not familiar with nginx, but shouldn't the values of `location` and `alias` be swapped? It makes more sense to me that way...

Answer (score 1):

Try to put

```
return          301 $scheme://test.example.org/dashboard;
```

inside

```
location / {
}
```

Comment: Not work, now the browser returns after 10-20 seconds "http://test.example.org:8080/dashboard/". "8080" is inserted and i have errors

Comment: 8080 is the port your server listening (as by your config). So if you see the URL you mentionned, the redirection works as expected. Now you should look where points `alias` directive and what files are there. By the way I suggest to replace `alias` by `root` with full path to files, as `alias` works sometimes strange.

Comment: With 'root' works, but "dashboard" not exists like physical path, and have 404 error

Comment: So rename your directory. Honestly I never managed to make `alias` work for my config. Nothing to do with redirection, but with many locations and rewrites. Try to look in the webserver's log with `alias` in place. It can give you a clue.

Comment: No, i not can modify the directory, not exist a way to remove the "8080"?

Comment: OK i resolved inserting `port_in_redirect off;` in nginx.conf. Now have another problem, when i go to test.exanmple.org/dashboard, nginx insert "/dashbord" at the beginning of URL and not find any files: es. "GET /dashboard/modules/notify/module.js HTTP/1.1" 404 199 "http://test.domain.com/dashboard/"

Comment: Did you try with `root` or `alias`. For `root` this is expected behavior. `alias` should replace the location path with the specified directory.

Comment: I use `alias`, with root nginx try to search a physical directory and not work, /dashboard not exist like physical

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it,

```
location / {

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args @goto_dashboard;
}

location @goto_dashboard {
    return 301 http://xxx/dashboard;
}
```